# Efficient way to build random undirected graphs without self loops given total number of graph nodes and associated node degree

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph, multiprocessing

I wrote an algorithm to build 1000 different random graphs given number of nodes and node degree. Node degree is maintained between the random graphs. I am building these random graphs to input to a statistical test which says given a certain graph what are the chances of finding certain edges by chance. My current algorithm is quite slow. Pseudo code below:

Data structure input to algorithm:

node_id : node_degree (dictionary) i.e node1 : 122, node2 : 33, node3: 66
List of edges (list) i.e. edge1,edge2,edge3...edgen

- For edge1 in ListofEdge:

  - Pick 2 random nodes node1(startnode), node10(endnode) to assign edge1 to

    - if node1 not reached node_degree:

      - add to dict random_graph1[node1] : edge1
    - if node10 not reached node_degree:

      - add to dict random_graph1[node10] : edge1
    - If edge assigned to both node move to next edge

During this simple pseudo-code I encounter conditions which I resolve:

Sometime only 1 node is left in the end while picking 2 random nodes and this single node has unassigned node degree, But I do not want self loops in my graph so I do below :

- If only 1 node left (node_z):

  - Look at current full graph and select 2 nodes at random (node_x, node_y):

    - Do these nodes have a connected edge between them:

      - break this edge (b/w node_x, node_y) + connect node_x to node_z + connect node_y to node_z
      - Keep breaking edges randomly until all nodes have reached node degree capacity.

Also every time a node is connected I check original dictionary to know if node degree reached or not.
At the moment to generate a random graph given 11,000 nodes and 136million edge my code takes 5 hours. I need a significant speed up as I need to build 1000 such graphs. Also this code is single processor. I could not figure out how to multiprocess as many shared data structures would need to be synchronised between processes.

Just putting part of my code that checks initial conditions:

```
success_dict = defaultdict(list)  
popped_dict = defaultdict(dict)
grid_dens_dict = defaultdict(set)
count = 0
all_itr_list = []

for iteration in range(1000):
    all_stop = False
    all_stop_2 = False
    count = count +1
    
    success_dict = defaultdict(list)  
    popped_dict = defaultdict(dict)
    grid_dens_dict = defaultdict(set)
        
    with open(filename2,'rb') as handle:
        pfxlinks = pickle.load(handle,encoding ='latin-1')  


    with open(filename3,'rb') as handle:
        grid_ids_withlinks = pickle.load(handle,encoding ='latin-1')
    
    for pfxpair in pfxlinks:
        start_put = False    
        end_put = False 
        
        if all_stop_2 == True:
            break
        
        while True:
            
            if all_stop == True:
                all_stop_2 = True
                break
           
            try:
                grid_start_id, grid_end_id = (np.random.choice(list(grid_ids_withlinks.keys()),size = 2, replace = False)) # get 2 random node ids
                grid_start_id = int(grid_start_id)
                grid_end_id = int(grid_end_id)
                
                if start_put == False:
                    
                    start_value = grid_dens_dict.get(grid_start_id)    # if node id exists in my dict and node degree hasnt reached capacity
                    
                    start_process_condition = (not start_value) or ( (start_value) and (len(grid_dens_dict[grid_start_id]) < grid_ids_withlinks[grid_start_id]) )
                    if start_process_condition:
                        grid_dens_dict[grid_start_id].add(pfxpair)
                        start_put = True
                    
                        if len(grid_dens_dict[grid_start_id]) == grid_ids_withlinks[grid_start_id]: # node degree for node full, remove from dict
                            
                            try:
                                #print('deleted key: ',grid_start_id, 'with size:',grid_dens_dict[grid_start_id],'Capacity:',grid_ids_withlinks[grid_start_id])
                                popped_dict[grid_start_id] = {'orig_capacity': grid_ids_withlinks[grid_start_id],'size':len(grid_dens_dict[grid_start_id]) }
        
                                grid_ids_withlinks.pop(grid_start_id)
                            
                            except:
                                print('already popped')
                else:
                    print('check')
                              
                if end_put == False: 
                    
                                        
                    end_value = grid_dens_dict.get(grid_end_id)
                    if (not end_value) or (end_value and (len(grid_dens_dict[grid_end_id]) < grid_ids_withlinks[grid_end_id])):
                        grid_dens_dict[grid_end_id].add(pfxpair)
                        end_put = True
                        
                        if len(grid_dens_dict[grid_end_id]) == grid_ids_withlinks[grid_end_id]:
                            try:
                                #print('deleted key: ',grid_end_id, 'with size:',grid_dens_dict[grid_end_id],'Capacity:',grid_ids_withlinks[grid_end_id])
                                popped_dict[grid_end_id] = {'orig_capacity': grid_ids_withlinks[grid_end_id],'size':len(grid_dens_dict[grid_end_id]) }
        
                                grid_ids_withlinks.pop(grid_end_id)
        
                            except:
                                print('already popped')
                else:
                    print('check')
                
                if (start_put == False and end_put == True):      # only end while when both nodes have been assigned a link
                    grid_dens_dict[grid_end_id].discard(pfxpair)
                    end_put = False
                if (start_put == True and end_put == False):
                    grid_dens_dict[grid_start_id].discard(pfxpair)
                    start_put = False
        
                        
                if start_put == True and end_put == True:
                    success_dict[pfxpair].append((grid_start_id,grid_end_id))
        
                    break
```

Comment: What is an "edge" in your list of edges? Are you guaranteed that the input provides enough edges to match the need to connect all your nodes with the prescribed node degree? Are you set in stone in terms of the format of your output? An adjacency matrix might work better than your current usage of dicts. I feel as if this whole question may be an [x/y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) in terms of your inputs/outputs.

Comment: @zephyr The edge list is just a placeholder for a list of edges. It might well as be a list like edge1,edge2,edge3.... 136millionth edge. The number of nodes and node degree is derived from an original graph which doesn't have self loops but has multiple edges, so yes it is realisable. I think such graphs can be thought of an isomorphic graphs. I do not care about input or output format as such. Only that I need to randomly build 1000 isomorphoc graphs of original given graph which are different from each other in an efficient way

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question though. If I were to do `type(edge1)` what would I get? And why do you even need to pass in edges anyway? You know how many edges must exist by your number of nodes and their degree. Can't you simplify your inputs by removing the need to specify edges?

Comment: @zephyr That is correct I might as well replace the line for pfxpair in pfxlinks: with for i in range(135million). But that single line doesn't change much in the whole algorithm ? type(edge1) is just string like (nodex,nodey)

Comment: So again, this sounds like an x/y problem. If you already have a graph with the proper set of nodes and connections, why are you trying to build an entirely new one from scratch that has the same properties? You can just shuffle edges around in your current graph randomly for as long as you want until you have a new graph. Just make sure to shuffle your edges appropriately so you maintain the node degree. If your graph is defined with an adjacency matrix, this whole process is as simple as moving 1's around in your adjacency matrix under a set of rules to maintain node degree.

Comment: @zephyr I had initially thought about starting with original graph and randomly shuffling nodes, but wasn't sure if this is random enough compared to building a graph from scratch. Since I am using this for a statistical test it should be unbiased and random. How would I go about your suggested method though? a few starting points

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133324/discussion-between-zephyr-and-skynaive).

Comment: @zephyr I forgot to mention my graph has multiple edges so I represent them with the number of edges corresponsding to that node? How would shuffle work in that case between 2 edges with different node degree?